# How can i set an Horizontal scroll or multiline text on a Combobox ? ( Vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

I ' ve a combobox with  too  long multiple Items . There is any method to set a horizontal scroll in combobox or set a multiline properties for each item ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow each item to use multiple lines in a Winforms Combobox (or Listbox)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001450/allow-each-item-to-use-multiple-lines-in-a-winforms-combobox-or-listbox)

Comment: mulitline violates the purpose of a combo, so no (although MS has some).  the width can easily be handled thru the `DropDownWidth` property; multiline text though is also doable in `DrawItem`

Comment: really ? How Can I do this in DrawItem ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> *Hi Mattia,*

There are a couple of methods that are usable as well as effective for this problem you are having, here is the concept that I've created that you may implement in your project;

**Original text:** C:\path1\path2\path3\path4\file.exe

**Combo Box text:** C:\path1\p...file.txt

To do this you will 1st have to specify how many characters you want to **shown in the start** of the text (1st 5 or so) then you must specify how much you would like to **leave off** at the end (last 6 or so).

I realize this causes a problem, *"I wont be able to see the full path!"*, however adding a **2nd form** or a **msgbox** to display the full text which should initiate the 1st 2-4 secs of display time, this should not be a challenge nor a problem and will make you look like a **Pro!**

*I hope this helped you with your problem or motivated you to go over and beyond!*